# Not able to hide the UI the second time when added, First time works perfectly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a use case where users can add items to a list and remove them, but the list cannot exceed 10 items. I've created an `Add Item` button to add UI elements and a `Remove Item` button to remove them using the `'display: 'none'` property. The issue arises when I add an item with an ID that was previously deleted. In such cases, I'm unable to hide or delete it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div.container {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            background-color: silver;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: silver;
            padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            color: '#000';
            font-size: 1.2vw;
            margin-left: 20px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }


        .main {
            margin-left: 13%;
            /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
            font-size: 1.5vw;
            padding: 0px 10px;
            margin-Top: 13%;
            padding-bottom: 50px;
            height: 100%;
            /* border: 1px solid blue */
        }

        .submitButton {
            height: 50px;
            width: 40%;
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-family: sans-serif
        }

        .addItemButton {
            height: 40px;
            width: 20%;
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            align-items: flex-end;
            justify-self: flex-end;
            font-family: sans-serif
        }

        .removeItemButtonView {
            height: 40px;
            width: 20%;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            align-items: flex-end;
            justify-self: flex-end;
            font-family: sans-serif
        }

        .submitButton:hover {
            background-color: #007893;
            color: #fff
        }

        input {
            height: 34px;
            width: 60%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin: 10px 0px;

        }

        .inputWidth {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .detailBox,
        .sceneBox {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: flex-end;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: silver;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sticky">
            <header>
            </header>
        </div>
        <!-- <article> -->
        <div class="main">
            <div class="cmdevice">
            </div>


            <button type="button" class="addItemButton" onclick="addItem()">Add Unit</button>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<script>

    let counter = 0
    let deviceArr = []

    const cmdevice = document.querySelector('.cmdevice');

    function addItem() {
        if (deviceArr.length >= 10) {
            return;
        }

        deviceArr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

        let newId = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < deviceArr.length; i++) {
            if (deviceArr[i] === newId) {
                newId++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        deviceArr.push(newId);
        console.log('newId', newId)
        let cmItem = document.createElement('div');
        cmItem.setAttribute("id", `cm${newId}`);
        cmItem.innerHTML = `<div style="border: 1px solid; border-radius: 25px; margin: 30px 0px" >
                    <div class="seperator" style="margin: 30px 0px; padding: 0px 20px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;   align-items: center">
                        <label>Device ${newId}</label>
                        <button type="button" class="removeItemButtonView" onclick="onClickRemoveCMItem(${newId})" >Remove Unit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailBox">
                        <div>Line Number</div>
                        <br>
                        <input class="input inputWidth" type="text" name="line${newId}" id="line${newId}" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailBox" style="border-bottom: 0px" >
                        <div>Area No</div>
                        <br>
                        <input class="input inputWidth" type="text" name="area${newId}" id="area${newId}" value="" />
                    </div>`;
        cmdevice.append(cmItem);
    }

    function onClickRemoveCMItem(id) {
        let ind = deviceArr.indexOf(id)

        console.log(deviceArr, id, ind)
        if (ind !== -1) {
            deviceArr.splice(ind, 1)

            console.log('del', id)
            const a = document.getElementById(`cm${id}`)
            if (a) {
                a.style.display = 'none'
                a.innerHTML = ''
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

I have tried various method to delete it. Every ting gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete it first time, you're setting `display` of 'cm1' to `none`, and when you again add an entry, you create another 'cm1'; while removing it second time, it finds first 'cm1' that's already lying with `display:none` and never reaches the current 'cm1'. Also, it's not advisable to use multiple elements with same `id`.

It's better to remove it from DOM. Use this instead of setting `display` -

```
function onClickRemoveCMItem(id) {
    let ind = deviceArr.indexOf(id)

    console.log(deviceArr, id, ind)
    if (ind !== -1) {
        deviceArr.splice(ind, 1)

        console.log('del', id)
        const a = document.getElementById(`cm${id}`)
        if (a) {
            a.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitika, this thing completely went off my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I read your code and executed in my local. So I can find what is the reason of your issue.

After first removing, assuem that first item, so its id is `cm1`. When your click the `Remove Unit` button, following code is executed in `if` statement.

```
a.style.display = 'none'
a.innerHTML = ''
```

This work with hidden and clear content, but it don't remove `a` in document. So the id `cm1` is exists in your html document.

[image]

So when you click the `Remove Unit` button secondly, the code works for first element that id is `cm1`. As a result you can think that dosen't work.

To fix this issue, You need to fix the remove logic. Following is my code. Thank you.

```
    function onClickRemoveCMItem(id) {
        let ind = deviceArr.indexOf(id)

        console.log(deviceArr, id, ind)
        if (ind !== -1) {
            deviceArr.splice(ind, 1)

            console.log('del', id)
            const a = document.getElementById(`cm${id}`)
            if (a) {
                // a.style.display = 'none'
                // a.innerHTML = ''
                a.remove() // added code
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to `hide` the element on clicking `Remove Unit`, then you just need to do this:

```js
  function onClickRemoveCMItem(id) {
    const element = document.getElementById(`cm${id}`);
    if (element) {
      element.style.display = "none";
      element.innerHTML = "";
    }
```

### Suggestion:

If you wantto actually **remove** the element rather than just hiding it, then the approach you are following doesn't seem very optimal. Instead, you can try proceeding like this:

**Give a unique `id` to your container:**

```html
<div id="device-container" class="cmdevice"></div>
```

**Initializing Variables:**

```js
<script>
  let deviceCount = 0;
  let uniqueIndexCounter = 0;

  const cmdevice = document.getElementById("device-container");
  // ....Rest code
```

**Add Device Logic:**

```js
function addItem() {
    if (deviceCount >= 10) {
      return;
    }

    deviceCount++;
    uniqueIndexCounter++;
    let cmItem = document.createElement("div");
    cmItem.setAttribute("id", `cm${uniqueIndexCounter}`);
    cmItem.innerHTML = `<div style="border: 1px solid; border-radius: 25px; margin: 30px 0px" >
                    <div class="seperator" style="margin: 30px 0px; padding: 0px 20px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;   align-items: center">
                        <label>Device ${uniqueIndexCounter}</label>
                        <button type="button" class="removeItemButtonView" onclick="onClickRemoveCMItem(${uniqueIndexCounter})" >Remove Unit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailBox">
                        <div>Line Number</div>
                        <br>
                        <input class="input inputWidth" type="text" name="line${uniqueIndexCounter}" id="line${uniqueIndexCounter}" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailBox" style="border-bottom: 0px" >
                        <div>Area No</div>
                        <br>
                        <input class="input inputWidth" type="text" name="area${uniqueIndexCounter}" id="area${uniqueIndexCounter}" value="" />
                    </div>`;
    cmdevice.append(cmItem);
  }
```

**Remove Device Logic:**

```js
  function onClickRemoveCMItem(id) {
    const elementToBeRemoved = document.getElementById(`cm${id}`);
    cmdevice.removeChild(elementToBeRemoved);
    deviceCount--;
  }
```